# Unexpected empty hash

Tags: java, android

I have this piece of code. The problem is in `this.hash` or `this.getHash()`. When I try to set hash value to method `checkHash()`, `Log.d` and `Server` (because `checkHash()` sends value to server) say that `this.hash` is `""`. Why `this.hash` becomes unexpectedly empty?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(...) {
...
Connection conn = new Connection(getApplicationContext());
this.hash = this.getHash();
Log.d("OMG", this.getHash()); // returns correct HASH value
Log.d("OMG", this.hash); // returns correct hash value
String response = conn.checkHash(this.hash, device); // this method gets empty hash value

...
}

}
```

EDIT 1

```
public String checkHash(String hash, String device) throws ServerException, NoInternetException {
    List<NameValuePair> query = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    Log.d("INTERNAL", hash + " / " + device);
    query.add(new BasicNameValuePair("hash", hash));
    query.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key", this.KEY));
    query.add(new BasicNameValuePair("device", device));
    query.add(new BasicNameValuePair("method", "checkHash"));
    return this.post(query);
}
```

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

```
        try {
            // Checking hash
            String device = Settings.Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

            Connection conn = new Connection(getApplicationContext());
            this.hash = this.getHash();
            Log.d("LOVEISTRUE", this.hash);
            String response = conn.checkHash(this.hash, device);

            Log.d("HAVEALOOK", device + " / " + response);
            Log.d("HAVEALOOKRESPONSE", response);
            if (response.equals("ERR")) {
                Intent toProjects = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                this.startActivity(toProjects);
            }
            if (response.equals("OK")) {}
        } catch (Exceptions.ServerException e) {
            Intent toProjects = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            this.startActivity(toProjects);
        } catch (Exceptions.NoInternetException e) {
            Intent toProjects = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            this.startActivity(toProjects);
        }
```

}

EDIT 2

03-31 20:50:02.226 25129-19694/com.mrgeorgeous.liceraptorapp D/HAVEALOOK: 2cd3c4a50347752781db11734b44c4dc
03-31 20:50:02.236 25129-19694/com.mrgeorgeous.liceraptorapp D/HAVEALOOK: 2cd3c4a50347752781db11734b44c4dc
03-31 20:50:02.246 25129-19694/com.mrgeorgeous.liceraptorapp D/HAVEALOOK: 2cd3c4a50347752781db11734b44c4dc
03-31 20:50:02.366 25129-25129/com.mrgeorgeous.liceraptorapp D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 732K, 10% free 8464K/9372K, paused 13ms, total 15ms
03-31 20:50:02.376 25129-25129/com.mrgeorgeous.liceraptorapp I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 9.844MB for 1481024-byte allocation
03-31 20:50:02.396 25129-25138/com.mrgeorgeous.liceraptorapp D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4K, 9% free 9906K/10820K, paused 21ms, total 22ms
03-31 20:50:02.436 25129-25129/com.mrgeorgeous.liceraptorapp D/INTERNAL:  / 5136389168f5aa53
03-31 20:50:03.546 25129-25129/com.mrgeorgeous.liceraptorapp D/HAVEALOOK: 5136389168f5aa53 / ERR1
03-31 20:50:03.546 25129-25129/com.mrgeorgeous.liceraptorapp D/HAVEALOOKRESPONSE: ERR1

Comment: instead of `getApplicationContext()` try `MainActivity.this`

Comment: please distinguish between `null` and `""` (empty string). They are conceptually different.

Comment: Can you show some code that gives us an idea what `getHash()` and `checkHash()` look like?

Comment: post your logcat please

Comment: done. please see edits

Comment: Sasha, it's more similar to "", cause there are no NullExceptions

Comment: @BadCash getHash() func returns SharedPreferences value. Just believe me, it works.

Comment: @helldawg13 please, see logcat in description

Comment: post the logcat where the crash is. Normally starts with caused by

Comment: @helldawg13 there is no crash